# How do I show dollar sign in a monospace font?

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

How do I show a dollar sign in monospace -- like `$124.12`? I tried the below method with no luck.

```
\verb$\$124.12$
\texttt{$124.12}
```

Thanks

Comment: `\texttt{\$124.12}`

Comment: Or `\verb+$124.12+`.

Comment: The first line of code doesn't work as you expect because the char immediately after `\verb` is the delimiter (all between the same delimiter is typeset verbatim, here "\" because it's surrounded by the `$` delimiter). The 3rd `$` in the first line is see as is (the begin of the math environment). The math environment ends with the `$` in the second line, but you obtain errors because in the math environment (`\texttt{`), there is a open brace without a close brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `\texttt` and `\verb` can get the job done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\$124.12} \verb+$124.12+ \verb/$124.12/
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` character is special in LaTeX. In order to *print* a $ character, you just do `\$`.

So you type

```
\texttt{\$124.12}
```

Avoid using `\verb` for typewriter type. It *uses* typewriter type, but it's meant for reproducing TeX code.

***Caution.*** With the legacy OT1 encoding, `\$` would print a *£* character with italic fonts (not with upright typewriter type). Load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` if you don't want to have surprises with `\$`.